# Parallel run with TASK

Tags: c#

Below my c# code is working fine.

```
public async Task<string> GetToken()
        {
            string token = createUniqToken();//This will return a uniq string 
            var lstData = getData(); //this will return list of data

            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            List<MyObj> lstValue = new List<MyObj>();

            foreach (var data in lstData)
            {
                if (data.IsSpecial)
                {
                    //********** CODE BLOCK 1 ********************

                    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetSpecialValues(token, data, lstValue)));

                    //analyse the lstValue and after analyzing, appropriate record will be save to the database

                    //********* END CODE BLOCK 1 ***************
                }
                else
                {
                    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await GetValues(token, data)));
                }

                Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
            }

            return token;
        }


        //Normal procidure fucntion
        private async Task GetValues(string resourceToken, DataDto objData)
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                //calling to below API and it takes 10 seconds to get a response.
                var result = await client.PostAsJsonAsync($"{baseUrl}api/services/app/Rate/GetRate", Request);

                //using above result directly save the responce values to the database and this method also workig totally fine

            }

        }

        //Special procidure fucntion
        private void GetSpecialValues(string resourceToken, DataDto objData, List<MyObj> lstValue)
        {
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            foreach (var session in objData.sessions)
            {
                tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CallToSpecial(session, lstValue)));
            }

            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        }

        private void CallToSpecial(Sessions session, List<MyObj> lstValue)
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                //calling to API and it takes 10 seconds to get a response.
                var result = client.PostAsJsonAsync($"{baseUrl}api/services/app/Rate/GeSpecialtRate", Request).Result;

                //using above result directly save the responce values to the database.

                MyObj obj = new MyObj();

                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var res = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<HttpResponse<ResultInput>>().Result;
                    obj.Id = res.Id;
                    obj.Value = res.Amount;

                    lstValue.Add(obj);//Assign response values to the list
                }

            }

        }
```

**Scenario explanation.**

There is a special scenario and normal scenario.
If the scenario is normal, it gives data to async APIs to execute parallel. inside the execution it will save relevant data to the database. (API takes 10 seconds to execute and no need to wait for a result. After comes data, it saves to the data base)
If the scenario is special, it have few tasks to run parallel and after getting all result, optimum result will be save to the database. (it is needed to compare all results for saving to the database in the special scenario.) If I explain further, I have a Task list and it should run parallel. Inside of that parallel Task there can have another Task list which needs to run parallel.)

Here is my only requirement. After calling "GetToken" function, it is returning unique string. But I need to return it within few milliseconds. But with above code it takes a lot of time to return mentioned token. The reason for that slowness is "CODE BLOCK 1". If I remove that part and run, can fulfill my requirement. it will return the token within few milliseconds, even though api execute takes 10 seconds. I did not use async await for "CODE BLOCK 1" because I need to assign response values to a list object. If I use async await for that, execution will not stop till get a response and, at the end of the execution lstValue will not assign any value.

Can any expert show me a direction to modify "CODE BLOCK 1" for fulfilling the requirement? (Should return the token within few milliseconds.)

> Updated working code.

This is 100% working code with console app.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<MyData> lst = new List<MyData>();

        lst.Add(new MyData()
        {
            Id = 1,
            IsSpecial = false
        });

        lst.Add(new MyData()
        {
            Id = 2,
            IsSpecial = false
        });

        lst.Add(new MyData()
        {
            Id = 3,
            IsSpecial = true
        });

        var tokn = GetToken();

        Console.WriteLine(tokn);
        Console.WriteLine("End Main Method!");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public static string GetToken()
    {
        Guid objGu = Guid.NewGuid();
        string token = objGu.ToString();
        List<MyData> lstData = new List<MyData>();

        lstData.Add(new MyData()
        {
            Id = 1,
            IsSpecial = false
        });

        lstData.Add(new MyData()
        {
            Id = 2,
            IsSpecial = false
        });

        List<Additional> lstAddi = new List<Additional>();


        lstAddi.Add(new Additional()
        {
            Id = 20,
            Amount = 101,
            Type = 1
        });
        lstAddi.Add(new Additional()
        {
            Id = 40,
            Amount = 201,
            Type = 2
        });
        lstData.Add(new MyData()
        {
            Id = 3,
            IsSpecial = true,
            Additionals = lstAddi
        });

        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        List<MyResult> lstValue = new List<MyResult>();

        foreach (var data in lstData)
        {
            if (data.IsSpecial)
            {
                //********** CODE BLOCK 1 ********************
                Console.WriteLine("Task block 1 started");
                tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetSpecialValues(token, data, lstValue)));
                Console.WriteLine("Task block 1 End");

                //********* END CODE BLOCK 1 ***************
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Task block 2 started");
                tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await GetValues(token, data)));
                Console.WriteLine("Task block 2 End");
            }
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine("Task wait 1 finished");

        return token;
    }


    //Normal procidure fucntion
    private static async Task GetValues(string resourceToken, MyData objData)
    {
        var sleepTime = objData.Id * 5000;

        RequestData req = new RequestData();
        req.val = sleepTime;
        Console.WriteLine("Normal | Will Sleep with this API " + req.val.ToString() + "ms");
        string cntent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(req);

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var content = new StringContent(cntent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            //will sent sleep time to the API and it gives the response after finishing the sleep time
            var result = await client.PostAsync($"https://localhost:44318/api/person", content);

            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var resData = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                //After getting the response, it's data directly save to the database
            }
        }
    }


    private static void GetSpecialValues(string resourceToken, MyData objData, List<MyResult> lstValue)
    {
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (var session in objData.Additionals)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CallToSpecial(session, lstValue)));
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine("Task wait 2 finished");
        foreach (var item in lstValue)//Will do calculations using this list and then it's values insert to the database
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Returned Values --> " + item.Value.ToString());
        }
        //To do the calculation it must fill the list

    }


    private static void CallToSpecial(Additional session, List<MyResult> lstValue)
    {
        var sleepTime = session.Id * 300;

        RequestData req = new RequestData();
        req.val = sleepTime;
        Console.WriteLine("Special | Will Sleep with this API " + req.val.ToString() + "ms");

        string cntent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(req);

        string resData = "0";
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var content = new StringContent(cntent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            //will sent sleep time to the API and it gives the response after finishing the sleep time
            var result = client.PostAsync($"https://localhost:44318/api/student", content).Result;

            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                resData = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
        }

        MyResult obj = new MyResult();
        obj.Id = session.Id;
        obj.Value = Convert.ToInt32(resData);
        lstValue.Add(obj);
    }
}


public class RequestData
{
    public int val { get; set; }
}

public class MyData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsSpecial { get; set; }
    public List<Additional> Additionals { get; set; }
}

public class MyResult
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class Additional
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I doubt the existing code is "working fine", because `StartNew` doesn't properly understand `async`.

Comment: Thanks @StephenCleary  checking my concern. I've added 100% working code. Can you check with it?